# Users can't log into XRDP that have not already logged in via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, vnc, xrdp

OS: Rocky 8.5

Joined to domain: SSSD

A domain user can ssh in, system notably makes the home directory and then the user can login via XRDP.

[image: xrdp login screen shows Xvnc]

I want to note that the login session show Xvnc instead of Xorg as I used to see when this was a CentOS 8 xrdp server.

But if a domain user does not login via ssh, first, then they get:

[image: User logs into xrdp server]

VNC Password failed... but its not supposed to be VNC...

So kind of unsensibly ignoring the fact that it says VNC, I imagined the user needs domain qualifer.

So I tried:

domainname\username

[image]

I think its sensible to assume that the Xvnc session is the wrong kind of session for an xrdp server. Am I right?
How do I fix this as usually when I install this stuff it shows "Xorg" and other options too.

The other major thing is that the user's home directory is not being made when they try to login which would definitely cause it not to log the user in.

Comment: This sounds like a shell environment issue rather than an actual need to ssh into the machine first.  This can be handled by proper shell configuration.  My guess is that the shell is unable to navigate to the user's home directory since it doesn't exist until they log into their account via ssh.  That is simple enough problem to solve as an administrator if that's the actual reason it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XRDP wasn't allowed by SELinux so had to:

```
sudo chcon --type=bin_t /usr/sbin/xrdp
sudo chcon --type=bin_t /usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman
```

and have to add this to /etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman to allow new xrdp users to make home directory on login:

```
account optional pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
```